# EXCEL conditional formatting by equal value in a column

Tags: excel, formatting, conditional-statements

I have this kind of set of data. I want to apply a conditional formatting rule that will highlight with 2 different colors the rows that have equal number in column A

[See this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9qY4i.png)

[The final result must be just like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k2NIr.png)

Answer (score 1):

Go to Conditional Formatting. Select option to choose new formatting rule. Then, choose to option where you can provide own formula. Then Enter this:
=AND($A2>0,MOD($F2,2)=0)

Choose a format and choose a color for all the rows where you have Group "2" in column F. If you also want to color the rows where you have Group "1". then add another formula with a small tweak to the one above:
=AND($A2>0,MOD($F2,2)=1)

Choose your colors for both cases and there you go.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem before, tell you how I handled it.

Two steps:

1. Get the distinct values from column A.

   - Click the Data ribbon menu > Fliter > Advanced
   - Fill in the setting dialog, copy the results to other places, and check "Unique records only"
   - [image]
2. Set conditional formatting

   - Set two different rules by formula:
     'lookup_value' = cell of column A
     'lookup_array' = distinct values

   > ```
   >  =MOD(MATCH('lookup_value','lookup_array',0),2)
   >
   >  =MOD(MATCH('lookup_value','lookup_array',0)+1,2)
   > ```

   - Choose background color and applied ranges(all of data)
     [image]

There may be a better solution, like use Excel VBA.
But I think this method is easier to understand.